# Import ES modules in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a JS library that provides a module.
I am importing it in my LWC like this example here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_third_party_library

Sadly, there is no example on how to import `d3` (if you look carefully you can see SF only import D3 in caps to reference resource, not the lib, and just rely on `d3` being global).

I tried importing from `'libname'` but i get the error that this is not a known LWC module.

If i try to import from resource/libname, i get the below.

> Invalid reference Resource/somelib.min.js of type resourceUrl in file myComponent.js

(Example module to try: https://github.com/flatpickr/flatpickr)

Without it everything works save for Intellisense in VS code and pesky warnings about functions being undefined.

*EDIT* the code works fine. I am asking how to get symbols into my code.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit - are you trying to find out how `d3` is being utilized or you are trying to import another 3rd party JS and would like to understand how to do that?

Comment: I want to understand how to use es-module `import x from ‘myscript’;` in lwc to avoid ‘undefined’ red squigglies in vs code.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The LWC compiler only resolves absolute import with the following form: `<namespace-name>/<lwc-module-name>`. Because of this, you can't directly import an NPM module via `import d3 from 'd3';`.

You have 2 options if you want to consume an es module from an lwc component:

- create a new lwc module (e.g. `d3` with a `d3.js`) and then import your module from your lwc component via the standard import syntax: `import d3 from 'c/d3';` ([lwc-recipe](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/68cd0e78fb1f2789fffc07377eb9e0f0c0aeee56/force-app/main/default/lwc/miscSharedJavaScript/miscSharedJavaScript.js#L2)). This approach should be avoided for large modules because they are sent and evaluated with your component and can create some performance issues.
- transform your es module to the UMD format and load it via a static resource ([lwc-recipe](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/68cd0e78fb1f2789fffc07377eb9e0f0c0aeee56/force-app/main/default/lwc/libsChartjs/libsChartjs.js#L56)). If the library attaches properties on the `window` object you should add them as [globals](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals) to your `.eslintrc.json` to avoid linting errors.

Comment: Would be interesting to see a deeper dive blog article on the pros/cons of these two import options and what the considerations are for each.  (e.g. What is considered a "large" module and how does it impact performance in different use cases?   Are there advantages to one or the other if the same module is used in a bunch of components on a page?)

Comment: Hi @pmdartus, could you please detail this answer with a 3rd bullet point and example to show how to import an LWC module from a 2GP namespaced package, now that this is deemed possible with LWS (cf https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.security_lwsec_locker_comparison) ?