# Use Three.js library in Lightning Web Component

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to migrate my Three.js code into a Lightning Web Component. My code uses the THREE namespace:

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
```

I uploaded the three.module.js as a static resource. But if I put the import statement in my .js-file I get the following when trying to deploy to my org:

```
import * as THREE from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/XXXXXV4/three.module.js';
```

> force-app/main/default/lwc/XXXX/XXXX.js-meta.xml  LWC1513:
> @salesforce/resourceUrl modules only support default imports.

I tried importing the library from another module but this exceeds the Salesforces size limit. Three.module.js has about 1.2 MB.

I read something about UMD format ( [Import ES modules in LWC](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252362/import-es-modules-in-lwc) ) (which is three.js or three.min.js) but how can I still use the THREE namespace than? Also I would have the problem that OrbitControls.js imports from THREE.

Thx a lot for your help!

Best regards

Max

Answer (score 0):

To use a third-party library, read [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/js_third_party_library).

You need to import the base resource file:

```
import THREE_LIB from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/XXXXXV4';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
```

...

```
connectedCallback() {
  loadScript(this, THREE_LIB + '/three.module.js')
  .then(() => {
    this.doWhateverHere();
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    // Deal with any errors here //
  });
 }
```

Once your promise has returned, you can now use the THREE library as normal.

Note that your script file should export the namespace:

```
export default THREE;
```

This will retain the namespace/name of the script.

Comment: Thx. I tried that. But I get **Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined** when using `console.log(e.message);` in the catch block

Comment: See also: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000XrWiQAK and https://www.bryntum.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=11981

Comment: Not working for me

Answer (score 0):

LWC Component expects a default export from the imported library.Here, in this case the three.js doesn't have a default export. You need to assign exports to the default property of exports. You can see this in the below image.

[image]

In the LWC Component, Use loadScript to load the three.js from static resource. Once the promise resolves, you are good to use it.

Here, in this example, I added a Zip folder with the following structure -> threeresource/three/three.js

```
import THREE_LIB from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/threeresource';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class ThreeJsTest extends LightningElement {
    connectedCallback() {

        loadScript(this, THREE_LIB + '/three/three.js')
        .then(() => {
            const scene = new THREE.Scene();
            const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('errorhere', error)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: not working for me