# LWC loadScript of Static Resource works on Local Development Server but not when deployed to Sandbox

Tags: lightning-web-components, static-resources

I used FullCalendar package to develop a rather simple LWC which includes a single DIV where the package dynamically loads it's elements.

```
<div id="calendar" lwc:dom="manual" class="fullcalendarjs"></div>
```

I developed the LWC using a **Local Development Server** (FullCalendar static resource was uploaded to a sandbox and then pulled into my project).

On the **local server** all is working perfectly, but when I deployed to the **sandbox** and tried displaying the LWC - I immediately hit an issue of accessing elements within the static resource (got an undefined value for them).

The loadScript promise resolves in both cases - however on the local server I get an event as a result and in the sandbox there's no event, the resolution is almost empty (not sure what does it mean - I'm not a JS expert).

Anyone ran into a similar issue? Any advice?

****** EDIT 01/09/2020*******

After some additional digging in the browser dev tools - I can clearly see that the resource is being loaded correctly - however - its path is different to the local server.

On the local server this is where my resource is located:

[image]

While on my Sandbox - the path is different:

[image]

On the local server I'm able to reference the FullCalendar var directly. When I try and do the same in the sandbox - it doesn't work and I get a ***FullCalendar is not defined*** error.

How should I address a var located in a different path?

Comment: This may be a Locker Service issue? Do you have the div where the calendar is to load marked as `lwc:dom="manual"`?

Comment: @sfdcfox yes, I do have this property on my div. Updated my description with the div code.

Comment: weird I've been using FullCalendar with LWC

Comment: What issues exactly are you facing?

Comment: What version of FullCalendar are you using?

Comment: I remember there are some issues with default usage of FullCalendarJS in LWC, so I used this modification https://github.com/Gurenax/sfdx-lwc-fullcalendarjs

Comment: Thanks @ytiq I saw this library - but it uses an older version of FullCalendar (v3.1). I was trying to use the most recent one v5.3. The issue is that my LWS js file doesn't recognize the constructor of FullCalendar - I get an undefined value. But as previously said - only in the Sandbox. On local server it works fine.

Comment: @ytiq if you'll look at the issues reported for the github you posted https://github.com/Gurenax/sfdx-lwc-fullcalendarjs/issues/4 you can see that others had experienced a similar(?) issue with loading scripts. I wonder if it's something really basic that I overlooked.

Comment: ye, unfortunately there seemed to be a little bit different implementations for LWC on dev server and Salesforce itself. But if you create update with the latest FullCalendarJS version, please upload it somewhere))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some help from Salesforce on this, and that's what they responded:

*As for accessing variable in the static resource, usually variables in static resources are private. In this case, you may need to attach the variable to the window object. For more details, please see:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_share_code.htm*

This solved my issue, but it is a bit of a hack. Salesforce should be allowing importing ES6 modules, possibly loading them into static resources.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to importing ES6 modules to LWC, I found this existing thread which discussed about 2 workaround options:
[Import ES modules in LWC](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252362/import-es-modules-in-lwc?rq=1)

If you feel that the feature is useful to you, I would highly recommend you to post it in our IdeaExchange site to raise awareness to our Product Management for future release consideration:
https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaSearch

Hope that helps :)

Cheers,
Aryne